# Generate a sequential number (per group) when adding a row to an Access table

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I have an MS Access (.accdb) table with data like the following:

```
Location Number
-------- ------
ABC      1
DEF      1
DEF      2
GHI      1
ABC      2
ABC      3
```

Every time I append data to the table I would like the number to be unique to the location.
I am accessing this table through MS Excel VBA - I would like to create a new record (I specify the location in the code) and have a unique sequential number created.
Is there a way to setup the table so this happens autmatically when a record is added?
Should I write a query of some description and to determine the next number per location, and then specify both the Location & Number when I create the record?

I am writing to the table as below:

```
    Set rst = New ADODB.Recordset
    rst.CursorLocation = adUseServer
    rst.Open Source:="Articles", _
         ActiveConnection:=cnn, _
         CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, _
         LockType:=adLockOptimistic, _
         Options:=adCmdTable
    rst.AddNew
    rst("Location") = fLabel.Location 'fLabel is an object contained within a collection called manifest
    rst("Number") = 'Determine Unique number per location
    rst.Update
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit - Added the VBA code I am struggling with as question was put on-hold

Comment: Is the Access database an `.mdb` file, or is it an `.accdb` file?

Comment: Hi - the DB is a .accdb file

Comment: Okay, good. Now find out if your environment is using Access 2010 (or newer). If it is, then [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/19762250/edit) your question with that information and ask if you might be able to accomplish your goal using a [Data Macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx). (Hint: You can.) Then, if your question gets re-opened, I can answer it.

Comment: Hi Gord - thank you very much for your assistance.
I am thinking long term, but if I was to migrate this to an SQL server sometime in the future a Data Macro wouldn't work. Ideally I would like to handle this in the Excel VBA code where the bulk of the code lies.
This is only a small part of the application in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that you are looking for something like this:

```vbs
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, cmd As ADODB.Command, rst As ADODB.Recordset
Dim newNum As Variant

Const fLabel_Location = "O'Hare"  ' test data

Set con = New ADODB.Connection
con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=C:\Users\Public\Database1.accdb;"

Set cmd = New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = con
cmd.CommandText = "SELECT MAX(Number) AS maxNum FROM Articles WHERE Location = ?"
cmd.CreateParameter "?", adVarWChar, adParamInput, 255
cmd.Parameters(0).Value = fLabel_Location
Set rst = cmd.Execute
newNum = IIf(IsNull(rst("maxNum").Value), 0, rst("maxNum").Value) + 1
rst.Close

rst.Open "Articles", con, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic, adCmdTable
rst.AddNew
rst("Location").Value = fLabel_Location
rst("Number").Value = newNum
rst.Update
rst.Close
Set rst = Nothing
Set cmd = Nothing
con.Close
Set con = Nothing
```

Note, however, that this code is **not** multiuser-safe. If there is the possibility of more than one user running this code at the same time then you *could* wind up with duplicate [Number] values.

(To make the code multiuser-safe you would need to create a unique index on ([Location], [Number]) and add some error trapping in case the `rst.Update` fails.)

### Edit

For Access 2010 and later consider using an event-driven Data Macro and shown in my [other answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19785633/2144390).

Comment: Thanks Gord. I am away from my desk today, I understand the above except for your "CreateParameter line and the one below it. I will give it a go and mark if solved when I can test it. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new column to your table of data type `AutoNumber`.

[office.microsoft.com: Fields that generate numbers automatically in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/access-help/fields-that-generate-numbers-automatically-in-access-HA001055067.aspx)

You should probably also set this column as your primary key.

Comment: Hi Danny,
Thank you for your response. I am not sure this is the solution that I am after. The number I need isn't unique to the table, but I do need it unique per location.
If I have misread your answer or missed some funcionality, then please enlighten me :)

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, I just re-read your question - you're right, this isn't what you want.

Answer (score 0):

For Access 2010 and newer, this is a better way to do it. It uses the table's `Before Change` Data Macro to derive the next sequential number and put it in the [Number] field of the new record:

[image: BeforeChange.png]

The advantages of this approach are:

- The sequence number will be applied whenever a new record is added, regardless of *how* it is added.
- The Excel VBA code does not have to worry about creating the sequence number; it "just happens".
- Since this code resides at the table level it *should* be safe for a multi-user environment.

For more information on Data Macros, see

[Create a data macro](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/create-a-data-macro-HA010378170.aspx)