# Select MAX ID Access database

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

I'm developing a School management System in vb.net with access db.
while accepting fees the receipt must be unique but starts from 1 in every new session
My using MAX ID query like

```
 str = "SELECT MAX([receipt_id]) FROM [Transaction] WHERE [session]=" & Home.Label2.Text
    cmd = New OleDb.OleDbCommand(str, cn)
    da.SelectCommand = cmd
    da.Fill(ds, "Transaction")
    Dim lastid As Integer
    If cmd.ExecuteScalar() Is DBNull.Value Then
        lastid = 0 + 1
    Else
        lastid = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.ExecuteScalar()) + 1
    End If

    receipt_no.Text = lastid
```

But the problem is it returns last id instead of max from that session.
Please can you help me out.

Here is the explanation my query is

```
SELECT MAX([receipt_id]) FROM [Transaction] WHERE [session]=2018-2019
```

The output will be 0 then 1 then 2 but when I fire

```
SELECT MAX([receipt_id]) FROM [Transaction] WHERE [session]=2019-2020
```

The output is 0 then 2 It returns max from the table transaction not considering where clause.

Comment: Not sure what is in session.values.  Would you clarify?

Comment: session.values are like 2019-2020 or 2020-2021 and goes on for every next year

Comment: I suspect that what you are trying to do would best be served by using an [autonumber field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoNumber) for the ID.

Comment: Where are you running this SQL? If it is an SQL statement in vb.net code, session.values needs to be concatenated or an embedded parameter.

Comment: If I use auto number then I can't make fees receipt id to start from 1 when user select other session. I'm using acces databse.

Comment: To Expand on what @AndrewMorton has said, think you've got a bit of a DB design issue going on here.  Any chance of seeing the db structure?

Comment: @JohnMcCalin Can you verify that by *session* you mean school session, rather than a computer-related session? Just to make sure.

Comment: Yes session means schools session not computer-related.

Comment: I Just want max number from table called transaction where session = 2019-2020. I think I wrote wrong query for max number.

Comment: Just edited with code

Comment: Related answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19785633/2144390).